# responsive container does not work with line chart (recharts)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, responsive, recharts

**thats my chart**

```
    <ResponsiveContainer width={"99%"} aspect={3}>
        <LineChart data={filterList.reverse()} >
          
        <XAxis  dataKey="timestamp" />
        <YAxis domain={['avg', 'avg']} />
        <Tooltip />
        <Line name="MMR" type="monotone" dataKey="avg" stroke={red[500]} activeDot={{ r: 10 }} />
        <Legend  />
                            
        </LineChart>
   </ResponsiveContainer>
```

**Rechart on desktop:**

[image]

**Rechart when window is resized:**
[image]

**Rechart when window is reloaded:**

[image]

Comment: Did you solve this - I'm having the same issue.

Comment: at the end i switched to chart.js and i got the same result i want it in rechart with less headache

Comment: ok, thanks for the reply.  don't think that will work in my case.